# Identity: How to add items to related fields

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity, code-first, identity

I want realise edit form, but error update item.
This is small example.

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities{ get; set; }
    public AppUser()
    {
        Cities = new List<City>();          
    }
}
```

And the a model for the City

```
public class City
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
    public City()
    {
        Users = new List<AppUser>();
    }

}
```

And the UserContext class  building up the one-to-many relationship between the 2 models.

```
public class UserContext: IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasMany(x => x.Users)
            .WithMany(x => x.Cities)
            .Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("CityId")
            .MapRightKey("UserId")
            .ToTable("UserCity"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And if I try update

```
UserContext db = new UserContext();
....
public ActionResult Edit()
{
 var newUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
 City city = db.Cities.FirstOrDefault();
 newUser.Cities = new List<City>() { city };
 newUser.SurName = "TestName";
 var result =  UserManager.Update(newUser);
 ....
}
```

I see error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
"The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because 
 they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."
```

If delete line

```
newUser.Cities = new List<City>() { city };
```

Error not show.
Why an error occurs when adding a field with many-to-many relationships?

Answer (score 0):

solution:  change from

```
var newUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

to

```
var newUser = db.Users.Include(x=>x.Cities).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id== userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Full list code change

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
 //var newUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
 City city = db.Cities.FirstOrDefault();
 newUser.Cities = new List<City>() { city };
 newUser.SurName = "TestName";
 //var result =  UserManager.Update(newUser);
 db.Entry(newUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();
 ....
}
```